# Testing wordpress site with Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to test my own wordpress plugin with `Cypress`.

I've encountered the following issue: if I add items to the cart with the built-in "Add to cart" button and navigate to the cart, it is empty.

If I try the same scenario manually with the cypress chrome browser beside the tests, the same thing happens.

Code:

```
it("puts in the cart", () => {
    cy.getChatbotIframe()
    .find("[data-cy=coupon-code]")
    .invoke("text")
    .then((text) => {
      cy.getChatbotIframe().find("[data-cy=go-to-cart-button]").click();
      cy.get("[data-cy=coupon-code]").contains(text);
    });
});
```

The `getChatbotIframe` command:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("getChatbotIframe", () => {
  return cy
    .get("[data-cy=alkubot-chat-iframe]", { log: false })
    .its("0.contentDocument.body", { log: false })
    .should("not.be.empty")
    .then((body) => cy.wrap(body, { log: false }));
});
```

[image: Screenshot of the error message]

Comment: Hi can you also post the custom command for `cy.getChatbotIframe()`

Comment: Do you get any errors ? if yes please post the screenshot. Also it would be helpful if you can post a screenshot of the DOM as well.

Comment: I've posted the screenshot. I think the DOM is not relevant, because if I use the wordpress builtin "Add to cart" button and I navigate to the cart manually inside the cypress opened chrome browser, it is empty

Comment: Assuming you have reached successfully till `cy.getChatbotIframe().find("[data-cy=go-to-cart-button]").click();`, so instead of `cy.get("[data-cy=coupon-code]").contains(text)` you can use something like `let getText = document.querySelector([data-cy=coupon-code]')[0].innerText; expect(getText).to.equal('expected text')`.

Comment: The problem is not with the text. The problem is that the item isn't added to the cart.

Comment: Try adding .should('be.visible') on the coupon code before clicking